# Storing Long Integer Array to a File

Tags: c

I have this code a global variable of `long int encryptedKey[100]`. Assuming that `encryptedKey` has stored values of type long int, I would want it to be written to a file. Below is my code for writing.
`ctr` is also a global variable and represents the number of values currently stored in `encryptedKey`

Writing to a file:

```
fptr = fopen("testme1.txt", "w"); 

    for (i = 0; i<ctr; i++) {
        fputc(encryptedKey[i], fptr);
    }
fclose(fptr);
```

Now, when I try to execute my readFile function, it does not read anything.

```
void readFile(){
    int num;
   FILE *fptr;

   if ((fptr = fopen("testme1.txt","r")) == NULL){
     
       exit(1);
   }
    printf("\n");
   fscanf(fptr,"%d", &num);

   fclose(fptr); 
}
```

I think it has something to do with my writing to the file but I can't seem to pinpoint where?

Comment: [link](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output) this looks oddly familiar

Comment: also, whats in the file after writing? care to post that?

Comment: @Shark unreadable characters. I checked the .txt file and just boxes

Comment: but... when you read them, in binary mode, do they match your key? 100 characters? so how do you suppose to read the whole file as a single `%lld` value?  when you're saving 100 `long int`s ?

Comment: My two cents: `fscanf` **parses** a _string_ from the provided stream into decimal, float, etc. and stores the typed result into the provided pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Function `fputc` shouldn't be used to write integer values into a file. Instead, `fputc(encryptedKey[i], fptr)` casts `encryptedKey[i]` to `unsigned char`, treats it as an ASCII value, and writes a corresponding character to the file.

According to Linux manpage:

> int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
>
> The fputc() function writes the character c (converted to an ``unsigned
> char'') to the output stream pointed to by stream.

You should use

```
for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
    fprintf(fptr, "%ld\n", encryptedKey[i]);
}
```

to write, and

```
for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
    fscanf(fptr, "%ld", &encryptedKey[i]);
}
```

to read.

If you don't know exactly how many values to read, you can use:

```
i = 0;
while(fscanf(fptr, "%ld", &encryptedKey[i]) != EOF) { 
    ++i; 
}
```